# Sending nested data in a POST request with angular

Tags: angularjs, http

I've got a `POST` request which I can't get to work properly due to some weird looking data parameters that I need to send with it.

Whilst this works:

```
return $http.post('/adcampaign/update_ads.json'
    + '?id=' + params.id
    + '&adcampaign_id=' + params.adcampaignID
    + '&ads[description]=' + params.description
    + '&ads[title]=' + params.title
    + '&ads[skip_offset]=' + params.skip_offset
    + '&ads[click_through]=' + params.click_through);
}
```

It creates parameters which I don't want, but it's the only way I've gotten it to work so far.

I tried doing this:

```
$http.post('/adcampaign/update_ads.json', {
    id: params.id,
    adcampaign_id: + params.adcampaignID,
    'ads[description]': params.description,
    'ads[title]': params.title,
    'ads[skip_offset]': params.skip_offset,
    'ads[click_through]': params.click_through
});
```

But that creates errors in the backend due to the `ads[prop]` data properties.

Writing it without the `'`s as `ads[prop]` throws a syntax error, as well as writing `ads['prop']`.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Should be creating property `ads` which is itself an object with properties.

```
var postData = {
    id: params.id,
    adcampaign_id: + params.adcampaignID,
    ads:{
        description: params.description,
        title: params.title,
        skip_offset: params.skip_offset,
        click_through: params.click_through
    }   
}

$http.post('/adcampaign/update_ads.json', postData) ;
```

To verify in php:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: Looks reasonable, but getting an error in the backend which I have to look into before I can say if it's the correct solution. I'll get back to you :)